# Modulus of Continuity for an Analytic Function on an Ellipse

Tags: cv.complex-variables, continuity, analytic-functions

Given $f\in C^{\infty} (E)$, where $E\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, define $E_{\rho} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ as the maximal ellipse with foci at $\{-1,1\}$ where $f$ is analytic, and semi-minor + semi-major axis summing to $\rho$.

**Question:** Is there any connection between $\rho$ and the modulus of continuity $\omega (\delta )$ of $f$ in $\lbrack -1, 1 \rbrack$?

Comment: Modulus of continuity of $f$ on $E$ or on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: $\lbrack -1 ,1\rbrack$, I'm changing it. Thanks

Comment: I think that there might be a counter example - $f_n = ne^{-\frac{x^2}{n^2}}$, an ever narrowing gaussians. Their modulus of continuitu grows larger, but isn't $E_{\rho} = \mathbb{C}$ always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a relation between $\rho$ and the modulus of continuity $\omega_{f}$ of $f$ on $[-1,1]$ which is obtained via the rate of polynomial approximation to $f$ on $[-1,1]$. Denote by $E_{n}(f)$ the distance from $f$ to polynomials of degree at most $n$ with respect to the uniform norm on $[-1,1]$. By the classical Jackson's theorem, 
$$E_{n}(f)\leq C\omega_{f}(1/n),$$
with $C$ some constant.
On the other hand, by the Bernstein-Walsh theorem (see e.g. the book Potential theory in the complex plane by T. Ransford for a reference), one has
$$\limsup_{n}E_{n}(f)^{1/n}= e^{-\inf_{\mathbb{C}\setminus E_{\rho}}g(z,\infty)},$$
where $g(z,\infty)$ denotes the Green function of $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$ with pole at infinity. Since the minimum of $g(z,\infty)$ is attained on the boundary of the ellipse $E_{\rho}$ and equals the constant value $\log\rho$ there, one derives that
$$\frac1\rho\leq\limsup_{n}\omega_{f}(1/n)^{1/n}.$$
In other words, a function with an "asymptotically" small modulus of continuity should admit an analytic continuation to a "large" ellipse $E_{\rho}$. Regarding your example (in the comment) of a narrowing gaussian, the left-hand side in the above inequality vanishes so nothing can be derived about its modulus of continuity.

Comment: Thanks! Can this entire derivation be found in some textbook/paper? Is there a lower bound on $\frac{1}{\rho}$ as well?

Comment: If $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $[-1,1]$ then $\omega_f(\delta)$ behaves like $C\delta$ as $\delta$ tends to 0, with $C$ the sup norm of $f'$ on $[-1,1]$. So the inequality actually simplifies to $1\leq\rho$ which is trivial, in particular not very useful, sorry for that...